# Loop breaks when executing function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the code below:

```
def scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus(access_token):

    query = "SELECT page_id FROM falken"

    result_list = c.execute(query)

    for single_row in result_list:

        str_single_row = str(single_row)

        str_norm_single_row = str_normalize(str_single_row)

        print(str_norm_single_row)
```

When I execute the code above, It displays every *single_row* values from *result_list*.

But when I pass *single_row* to a function like below:

```
def scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus(access_token):

    query = "SELECT page_id FROM falken"

    result_list = c.execute(query)

    for single_row in result_list:

        str_single_row = str(single_row)

        str_norm_single_row = str_normalize(str_single_row)

        print(str_norm_single_row)

        statuses = getFacebookPageFeedData(str_norm_single_row, access_token, 100)

        for status in statuses['data']:

            query = "INSERT INTO falken_posts VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

            c.execute(query,(processFacebookPageFeedStatus(status, access_token)))

            conn.commit()
```

It only passes the first value of *single_row* to the function and the loop stops.

**getFacebookPageFeedData** function

```
def getFacebookPageFeedData(page_id, access_token, num_statuses):

base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6"
node = "/%s/posts" % page_id 
fields = "/?fields=message,link,created_time,type,name,id," + \
        "comments.limit(0).summary(true),shares,reactions" + \
        ".limit(0).summary(true)"
parameters = "&limit=%s&access_token=%s" % (num_statuses, access_token)
url = base + node + fields + parameters

# retrieve data
data = json.loads(request_until_succeed(url))

return data
```

It retrieves data from Facebook Graph API of posts from pages.

**processFacebookPageFeedStatus** function

```
def processFacebookPageFeedStatus(status, access_token):

    status_id = status['id']
    status_message = '' if 'message' not in status.keys() else \
        unicode_normalize(status['message'])
    link_name = '' if 'name' not in status.keys() else \
        unicode_normalize(status['name'])
    status_type = status['type']
    status_link = '' if 'link' not in status.keys() else \
        unicode_normalize(status['link'])

    status_published = datetime.datetime.strptime(
        status['created_time'],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000')
    status_published = status_published + \
        datetime.timedelta(hours=-5) # EST
    status_published = status_published.strftime(
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    num_reactions = 0 if 'reactions' not in status else \
        status['reactions']['summary']['total_count']
    num_comments = 0 if 'comments' not in status else \
        status['comments']['summary']['total_count']
    num_shares = 0 if 'shares' not in status else status['shares']['count']

    reactions = getReactionsForStatus(status_id, access_token) if \
        status_published > '2016-02-24 00:00:00' else {}

    num_likes = 0 if 'like' not in reactions else \
        reactions['like']['summary']['total_count']

    num_likes = num_reactions if status_published < '2016-02-24 00:00:00' \
        else num_likes
```

It stores needed data from **status** dictionary and stores it to variables for inserting into database.

Comment: what is "c" ???

Comment: Please fix your code indentation.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers c is a sqlite cursor

Comment: What is `getFacebookPageFeedData` and `processFacebookPageFeedStatus`? Please edit your post to give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's not clear what's actually going wrong here, and there's a number of unknowns in the code, as well as incorrect indentation.

Comment: @languitar The indentation is just fine, when I execute the code I don't get IndentationError

Comment: When I looked at your question it wasn't indented yet.

Comment: Try using a different cursor for the inner for loop query.

Comment: While the edit shows more about your code, it does not provide a _minimal_ nor _complete_ example as described by my link. Now I'm looking at `request_until_succeed()` which is now not defined and certainly looks, based purely on the function name, like it's a point at which the code might hang on the first iteration.

Comment: I have managed to get it working using @abhilash's suggestion, presumably I cannot use the same cursor on a nested loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlite's `cursor.execute()` returns the cursor itself. So after this line:

```
result_list = c.execute(query)
```

`result_list` is actually an alias for `c`.

Now you start iterating over `c`:

```
for single_row in result_list:
    # code here
```

and then call `c.execute()` again:

```
    query = "INSERT INTO falken_posts VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    c.execute(query,(processFacebookPageFeedStatus(status, access_token)))
```

which discards `c`'s previous result set with the result of this new query. Since this query doesn't select anything, `c` becomes an empty iterator, and your loop stops there.

The cure is plain and simple: use another cursor for the insert queries so you don't overwrite `c`'s result set:

```
# create a second cursor for insert statements
writer = conn.cursor()
# no need to recreate this same string anew for each iteration, 
# we can as well define it here once for all
insert_query = "INSERT INTO falken_posts VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

# no need for result_list - just iterate over `c` 
c.execute(query)
for single_row in c:
    # code here
    writer.execute(insert_query,(processFacebookPageFeedStatus(status, access_token)))
```

As a side note, if performances are an issue, you may also want to commit only once after the whole loop instead of after each insert statement.

Comment: @JeremyCenteno glad I could help - and please do not forget to accept the answser then ;)